# osmdroid Polygon - adding a new point in a triangle

Tags: android, polygon, osmdroid

I can make a polygon using the `singleTapConfirmedHelper()`. But I still have a problem. How do I remove the line(blue arrow) when adding a fourth point(red circle). The line does not disappear after I add the fourth point. I hope I explained it well. Thank you.

```
    @Override
    public boolean singleTapConfirmedHelper(GeoPoint p) {

    Polygon circle = new Polygon();
    circle.setPoints(Polygon.pointsAsCircle(p, 2.0));
    circle.setFillColor(0x12121212);
    circle.setStrokeColor(Color.RED);
    circle.setStrokeWidth(2);
    map.getOverlays().add(circle);
    circle.setInfoWindow(new 
    BasicInfoWindow(org.osmdroid.bonuspack.R.layout.bonuspack_bubble, 
    map));
    circle.setTitle("Centered on " + p.getLatitude() + "," + 
    p.getLongitude());

    List<GeoPoint> pts = new ArrayList<>();
    pts.add(new GeoPoint(p.getLatitude(), p.getLongitude()));

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon(ctx);
    polygon.setTitle("This is a polygon");
    polygon.setSubDescription(Polygon.class.getCanonicalName());
    polygon.setFillColor(0x12121212);
    polygon.setVisible(true);
    polygon.setStrokeColor(Color.BLACK);
    polygon.setStrokeWidth(4);
    polygon.setInfoWindow(new 
    BasicInfoWindow(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble, map));
    polygon.setPoints(pts);
    map.getOverlays().add(polygon);

    map.invalidate();

    return true;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are drawing new polygon for each point added and you are not removing old ones. So theMapView will draw them all one over another. You should remove previously drawn polygon from list of overlays before calling map.invalidate().

```
Polygon polygon = new Polygon(ctx);
polygon.setTitle("This is a polygon");
polygon.setSubDescription(Polygon.class.getCanonicalName());
polygon.setFillColor(0x12121212);
polygon.setVisible(true);
polygon.setStrokeColor(Color.BLACK);
polygon.setStrokeWidth(4);
polygon.setInfoWindow(new 
BasicInfoWindow(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble, map));
polygon.setPoints(pts);
map.getOverlays().add(polygon);
if (oldPolygon != null) {
   map.getOverlays().remove(oldPolygon);
}
oldPolygon = polygon;

map.invalidate();
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I added the if condition above, now it doesn't draw the lines only the points.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped there, it's oldPolygon that should be removed. "map.getOverlays().remove(oldPolygon)". I'll fix that line in the response.

Comment: OMG!! Thank you very much. As you can see I posted this on June 16, I skipped this part on my project because it's driving me crazy. I should really work on my logic. Thank you Josef. I really appreciate it. But I'm still confused, how can we remove the oldPolygon when we didn't even add it in the first place?

Comment: @MarkA. Actually we did add it. The thing is the variables you are using in code are just pointers to real objects in memory. So when you add a polygon to overlays you are actually adding object to which points variable named polygon. And as you can see, later we are storing same object in variable named oldPolygon. So when we are trying to remove oldPolygon from overlays, it points to same polygon we added in previous execution.

Comment: Thank you very much Josef. You didn't just gave me a working code but also gave me an understanding. Again, thank you very much. I can now continue this part of my project.